# Probability of getting "war" in a Game of War (card game)

Tags: probability

I am coding War as a game, and I was wondering what the probability of getting "war" would be. I am probably wrong, but when each player has 26 cards (`52/2`), the chance of getting the same card value (like 2x Jacks), would that be `100/26 = 3.84615385%`?

I assume not, because: Each game loses at least 2 cards from the total, which would make the next iteration be `100/25 = 4%` chance of starting a war. The next would then be `100/24`... I think you get the point. When both players have 1 card (assuming you don't *steal* the cards), the chance of starting a war would be `100/1 = 100%`, which is wrong.

How am I supposed to calculate this correctly? I want to know **the probability of starting a war (2 of the same cards)** as well as **the probability of starting a war within a war (2 of the same cards within a started war)**. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Oh I think I forgot this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game)#Gameplay

**EDIT 2:** If we assume there are 52 cards total and I pick a random card. Then there are **51** cards left in the deck. **3** of those have the same value as my card, which makes that a `3/51 = 0.0588235294%` chance of starting a war.

Comment: Out of curiosity where are you getting the value 100 from?

Comment: @fleablood `1/26 * 100` and `100/26` is the same in this connection, no? Percentage calculation would be my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of getting a war on the first hand is 1/17 because whatever Player 1 card is there are 3 out of 51 cards that are the same rank.

From then on it's complicated conditional probabilities.

Call Player 1's first card R1, and Players 2's first card S1.  If R1 $\ne$ S1 (16/17 probability) and Players 2's second card (R2) is neither R1 nor R2 (a 44/50 = 22/25 probability) then there 3/49 probability that player 2's second card is a war (16/17*22/25*3/49).  But if R2 = (R1 or S1) (a 6/50 = 3/25 probability then there is a 2/49 that the second hand is a war.  Or

So the probability of  hand1 not a war  hand2 being war is 16/17(22/25*3/49 + 3/25*2/49).

But if hand1 was a war the probability of the second hand being a war is: if R2 = R1 = S1, (a 2/50 = 1/25 probability) then the probability is 1/49 (total: 1/17*1/25*1/49) but if R2 $ne$ R1 (a 48/50 = 24/25 probability) then the probability of a war is 3/49 (total: 1/17*24/25*3/49)

So the probability of hand 2 being a war is

16/17(22/25*3/49 + 3/25*2/49) + 1/17(1/25*1/49 + 24/25*3/49) =

(16(22*3 + 3*2) + 1 + 24*3)/(17*25*49)=

(16(72)+72 + 1)/17*25*49 = (17*72 + 1)/17*25*49 = 1/17

So basically every hand the probability of a war is 1/17.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense after I read some more about it myself. Thanks for further explanation!

Comment: Well, the probability of getting a war on *any* hand without knowing any history is 1 in 17.  Knowing any history changes things though.  The odds of a war within a war (without knowing any other hands) is (given that there *was* a war) is 73/25*49.

Comment: Given that the hand before wasn't a war or given that the hand before was a war will each have slightly skewed odds.  (72/25*49 vs. 73/25*49) Both are very close to 1 out of 17 but having had a war the odds of a second ware are *slightly* higher with seems kind of unintuitive to me.  Now if you've been counting cards and you are halfway through the deck... well the probability of a war will vary by the exact history.

Comment: Yeah that would make sense. So 1/17 sounds reasonably fair :) Thank you!